# How to get the value from the optional

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

How to get the value from optional?

**My model (`SearchModel`)**

```
var restaurantsearchname:String?
var offerModel:OfferModel?

init(withmodel  newrestaurantModel:OfferModel) {
     offerModel = newrestaurantModel
     print(offerModel?.name)
     print(offerModel?.id)
     restaurantsearchname = offerModel?.name
     print(restaurantsearchname)
}
```

**In my `viewController`:**

```
let searchmodel = searchViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
print(searchmodel)
let dataSourceModel:DataSource = DataSource(array: nil)
let viewModel:ViewModel = ViewModel(withdatasource: dataSourceModel)
let oo:SearchModel = SearchModel(withmodel: viewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
print(oo)
```

Here I need to print the `searchmodel.offerModel.id`. While printing it shows as `nil`.

But when I printed `print(offerModel?.id)` in model, here I got the value. But not get in `print(searchmodel.offerModel?.id)` from `viewcontroller`.

How to get the value?

Comment: this question is not very clear. which is probably why you have no answers. What you are trying to do seems a little over complicated. Try to simplify it. You may need to post the code for the other mentioned classes like `SearchModel` so we can understand how things are being set. where does the data actually come from? does `viewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)` not return OfferModel data in it?

Comment: i got output :-give print(oo.offerModel?.id)

Comment: Yet again MVVM overcomplicates things